# How to add the env URL to the container

Tags: docker, cypress

I want to run Cypress in Docker interactively. For this started the following cmd-line:

```
docker run -it --rm \
    --network host \
    -v ~/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:ro \
    -e DISPLAY \
    -v $PWD:/e2e \
    -w /e2e \
    --entrypoint '' \
    cypress/included \
    npx cypress open
```

That starts master display where I can select the browser. Upon selecting one, I see all my tests. However, if I run them, the correct URL is missing. Without Docker I pass it via the env variable. (--env https://ABC:1234 -- the instance is running on an other server). But env is already occupied with DISPLAY. Also exporting DISPLAY or BASE_URL etc. no luck so far.

Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: You can definitely use a `-e` option multiple time, see in the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#env

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε: of course I tried that: .env CLIENT_HOST=https://URL but then you get: ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(240)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
ERROR:env.cc(255)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting

Answer (score 0):

I found that the correct command is:

docker run -it --rm 
--network host 
-v ~/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:ro 
--env DISPLAY 
-v $PWD:/e2e 
-w /e2e 
--entrypoint '' 
cypress/included 
npx cypress open 
--env CLIENT_HOST=Server_URL

It seems that the  position of e->CLIENT_HOST needs to be after "npx cypress open" and not next to -e=Display